# YOLO: How to label small objects?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolov5, labelimg

In the given image, orientation of the bags is not uniform, so difficult to label the sacks. How to label this kind of image in .txt(YOLO) format?
What if I have multiple objects next to each other like in the following picture:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whGAQ.jpg]

Comment: You can crop these into different files and do it one by one. Also, you can use github.com/tzutalin/labelImg as an alternative if the process fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with labelling like these images no issue with the overriding of the box on box or object on the object, because while you are training the YOLO algorithm, it will take only the coordinates of the object or that part of the image so there will be no issue. try to train more images to get good accuracy

Comment: I appreciated the information you sent through, Thank you.